# Get person info from Clearbit.com using PHP. Web Site Development

Tags: php, oauth

i am using this code in order to get persons info by email

to post it on web page

In API documentation (https://dashboard.clearbit.com/docs?shell#oauth) http request looks like this

```html
HTTP REQUEST
GET https://person.clearbit.com/v2/combined/find?email=:email
```

I am try to do  this in PHP (p.s. I hid my key in the example)

```html
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://person-stream.clearbit.com/v2/combined/find?email=alex@clearbit.com'");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("-u: api-key-here*** "));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print($result);
?>
```

But this what i get

```html
{ "error": { "type": "auth_required", "message": "Authentication is required for this action. Sign up at https://clearbit.com" } }
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to authorize with an access token, the documentation you linked has a clear description of what steps to take to get yourself authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Provide your API key as the basic auth username.

But you sending just Authorization header.
So replace this line,

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("-u: api-key-here*** "));
```

by this line.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
```

so here `$username = your apk key` and leave `$password` as null.

ex:-

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"apk_key:");
```

Comment: happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response, it seems to be like it requires authentication token. You will need to send authentication token in request header along with your request.